# Yii2 UrlManager rules

Tags: yii2, yii2-urlmanager

What would be the Urlmanager rule for changing a url like site/product?name=[name] to product/[name]?

I tried

```
'<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
'product/<id:\d+>' => 'product',
```

But it gives me a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering to your question a short explain what is wrong.
You try to pass alpha chars to an action that handles only integers.
The rule `'product/<id:\d+>'` indicate that the url should be like:

```
product/1
product/777
product/8888
```

The regular expression `\d+` limits this url part to an integer.

**Answer**

For url like `product/[name]`, you should add this pattern:

```
//...
'product/<name:[\w]+>' => 'product/item',
//...
```

Where `'product/<name:[\w]+>'` will match any url like:

```
product/any
product/alpha
product/productname
```

The `<name:[\w]+>` will be the parameter that will hold matched url part and and creates a variable named `$name` that will contain only the alpha chars, due the regular expression `[\w]+`. This variable will be passed to controller action.

And `'product/item'` is the controller / action that will handle request, in this example is `ProductController` and `actionItem` with parameter `$name`.

Now in ProductController you need to add an action:

```
//...
/**
 * Handle products by name
 * @param string $name
 */
public function actionItem($name) {
   // ... do stuff here
}
//...
```

More information can be found here [Yii2 Routing and URL Creation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#url-rules).

Comment: Thank you so much. I had actually tried that, but it wasn't working because I had spaces.  I switched them to underscores and it works great now. Thanks!